# How to add CorsConfiguration in Eureka Discovery service in reactive springboot?

Tags: spring-security

I have a Eureka server deployed in Springboot.  I have enabled spring security with this maven dependency and yaml property for username/password:

```
<dependency>
 <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
 <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId> <!-- Provide basic auth for Eureka client registration -->
</dependency>
```

The following block shows my springboot version and webflux usage:

```
<parent>
 <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
 <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
 <version>2.7.3</version>
 <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>

<groupId>me.sonam</groupId>
<artifactId>discovery-service</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>eureka-service</name>
<description>Eureka Discovery Service</description>
<properties>
 <java.version>16</java.version>
 <spring-cloud.version>2021.0.4</spring-cloud.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
 <dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-server</artifactId>
 </dependency>

  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-webflux</artifactId>
  </dependency>
```

This is how I set my basic/auth security with username/password:

```
spring:
  security:
    user:
      name: ${EUREKA_USER}
      password: ${EUREKA_PASSWORD}
```

I have set CorsConfiguration as follows:

```
import org.springframework.web.cors.CorsConfiguration;
import org.springframework.web.cors.reactive.CorsConfigurationSource;
import org.springframework.web.cors.reactive.UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource;


@EnableEurekaServer
@SpringBootApplication
public class EurekaServiceApplication {
    private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(EurekaServiceApplication.class);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(EurekaServiceApplication.class, args);
    }


    @Bean
    CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource() {
        CorsConfiguration corsConfig = new CorsConfiguration();
        corsConfig.setAllowedOrigins(List.of("*"));
        corsConfig.setMaxAge(3600L);
        corsConfig.addAllowedMethod("*");
        corsConfig.addAllowedHeader("*");

        UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", corsConfig);
        return source;
    }
}
```

When I build my project with `mvn clean install` I get the following error:

```
 Bean named 'corsConfigurationSource' is expected to be of type 'org.springframework.web.cors.CorsConfigurationSource' but was actually of type 'org.springframework.web.cors.reactive.UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource'
```

Answer (score 2):

Replace your

```
import  org.springframework.web.cors.CorsConfigurationSource
```

with

```
import  org.springframework.web.cors.reactive.CorsConfigurationSource
```

Spring Framework has 2 classes named `CorsConfigurationSource`, one inside the reactive package and one in the outer package. Also the same for `UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource`. But you have imported `CorsConfigurationSource` from outer(non reactive) package and `UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource` from the reactive package. Therefore the issue you have.

Comment: I am using the classes from reactive package.  I updated the code with the imports.  Yet, the error still happens.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that there is no reactive package for Eureka server in the spring-cloud-netflix-eureka-server-3.1.4.jar (that's the version I am using).

So even if I add the following code:

```
import org.springframework.web.cors.reactive.CorsConfigurationSource;
import org.springframework.web.cors.reactive.UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource;

import java.util.List;

@EnableWebFluxSecurity
@EnableReactiveMethodSecurity
public class SecurityConfiguration {
    private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(SecurityConfiguration.class);

    @Bean
    public SecurityWebFilterChain securityWebFilterChain(ServerHttpSecurity http) {
        // @formatter:off
        LOG.info("configure securityWebFilterChain");

        return http.csrf().disable().cors().disable().build();
    }
```

The above doesn't get picked up.  However, the following SecurityConfig gets picked that doesn't use the reactive package for disabling csrf and cors, which I wanted to check if they were causing my registration issues::

```
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;

@Configuration
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.csrf().disable().authorizeRequests().anyRequest().authenticated().and().httpBasic();
    }

}
```

So now I am able to use spring-security on Eureka server with basic-auth.  My clients can do basic-auth and register their instance to that Eureka server.